# Bootstrap Scroll Spy with Sticky Navbar not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I'm having a problem with Bootstrap **Scrollspy** component.

I'm using a `sticky-top` navbar and when the nav button is clicked it scrolls to the correct element;

But the problem is that the sticky navbar is overlaying this element.

I tried using `data-offset = "50"` in the body tag but it affected nothing.

The body tag:

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sectionsNav" data-offset="50">
```

The body tag css:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div id="sectionsNav">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills text-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#wihe">What is Home Eats</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#hiw">How it Works</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#pws">Problems we Solve</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#jhen">Join Now!</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

How it works div:

```html
..
<div id="hiw" class="container">
...
..
.
</div>
..
```

Expected Behavior on clicking *How it works* button in the nav:

[image: Expected Behaviour image]

Occurring Behaviour:

[image: Occurring Behaviour image]
**Note That:** The navbar is above *How it Works* header.

## Edit

After applying @SMAKSS answer the scroll worked as charm. But another problem occured, in the navbar the highlighted element becomes the previous element.

At the following screenshot I pressed on *How it Works* and it scrolled correctly, But the highlighted navbar element is *What is home eats* which is the previous one.
[image: Incorrect highlighting]
i.e. If I clicked on *Problems we Solve*, *How it Works* becomes selected. It always select the previous one.

### Edit Solution

I fixed the second problem by doubling the `data-offset` attribute to be **100**.
the code now looks like this:

```html
<head>
 <style>
    html {
    scroll-padding-top: 70px;
    }

    body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    }
 </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sectionsNav" data-offset="100">
...
.
</body>
```

Comment: I got the best results with the same values for `scroll-padding-top: 60px` and `data-offset="60"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here happens because of **when an element with position `fixed` came into the play browser will still jump to the desired `id` but won't determine the element with position fix is still there** so it will ignore its `height` and will jump where ever the element with specific `id` match the window top element.

So you should let browser now in each scroll you need padding on jumping like this:

```css
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 70px; /* height of sticky header */
}
```

This is the full [article](https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-on-page-links-and-overlapping-content-oh-my/) that might help more.

### UPDATE

As we have gone further on this solution since the scroll spy will only know whether we are in a section with specific id or not the spying behavior crashed. So to fix this there are several approaches like adding `padding` to each section according to navbar `height` or as @Raamyy suggested approach, **we can define `data-offset` on our `body` tag, again with the height of the fixed navbar**. For more information about `data-offset` you can read [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#options).

Comment: @Raamyy So this behavior happens because you are still in the previous section and didn't enter the how it works section, to fix this there are several approaches. One can be apply padding in each section. So if you want to apply such a thing you should apply the navbar height as the top padding of your section. If you can share your section codes, I can help with that.

Comment: I doubled the data-offset from 50 to 100 and it worked as expected. I will edit the original post and add this solution. Thanks again!

Comment: spent hours on this, and dozens of other stackoverflow answers couldn't do it. this answer finally worked for me